# Undo/Redo with MVVM using a circular queue of lazy references

Tags: c#, design-patterns, stack, undo-redo

I'm using MVVM and WPF 4.5 Ribbon to activate views. Each activate command looks like this:

```
public void ActivateSearchDocuments()
{
    DisplayName = "Seach Documents - App";
    ActivateItem(IoC.Get<SearchViewModel>());
}
```

I know I can implement an Undo/Redo pattern using a circular queue. My doubt is: is it possible to store lazy references on that queue. I mean, how can I store that command on the queue in order to call it later.

I don't think delegates is the appropiate way. Is there something cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

Command design pattern can give you ability to Undo/Redo
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx#_self2

Comment: +1 However, the Command pattern cannot be used to create a complete undo facility on its own (althoug it is the answer in this case). You would need the Memento Pattern for a complete implementation...

Comment: @zzfima Problem isn't the pattern. I alreay let clear that. Problem is the implementation without delegates. Thanks but I don't see how this solves the question.

Comment: This is not clear how Command pattern can be leveraged for Undo/Redo implementation, too broad I would say